# Prevent/Slow down oxidation of organic material

Tags: redox, oxidation-state, color, organic-reduction

I'm having the hobby to draw paintings with the tea I drink trough the day. Usually I pour a tablespoon of the hot tea away, wait until it dries and gets more concentrated, so the colour is more intense.

Most of the colours are dark greens or variants of brown. Mostly due to the oxidation.

To get blue and red I now drink tea of herbs and flowers with such colours, and have to pour the sip away early to preserve the brighter tones.
Unfortunately after some time more than 80% of the dried tea becomes brownish.

I added some cold water to slow down the oxidation, but not much success, all I got was a small blue ring around a brown area.
Next to my office is a small laboratory where I asked what to use, but no idea from that side.

As I'm not a chemist I just did a simple calculation: The opposite of oxidation is reduction, so I need some Reducing agent. Used Ascorbic acid with not huge success.
Against rust and other effects of oxidation I can use industrial alcohol, so tomorrow I'll get a bottle of that. But as said, I'm just guessing here.

What can I actually use to hold or slow down the oxidation-process until the tea is dry?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just these herbal or floral teas which are oxidising you may wish to try adding some sort of colorless antioxidant compound to the teas. What I would attempt is blending your herbal and standard teas together. There are boat loads of antioxidants in tea. If your herbal teas are lacking in antioxidants, a splash of green tea may help.

Comment: Sulphites are used in wines to reduce/prevent oxidation so could be worth trying

Comment: @Waylander - thanks for the idea. Can you recommend a certain chemical?

Comment: If the original tea turns to the wrong colour - why would a tea that oxides itself support another tea which has an even stronger oxidation?

Comment: Sodium sulphite (sulfite) looks a good candidate, used in food processing so safe to ingest in small quantities

Comment: @Waylander - I give it a try